# Lifecycle Policy: Set Minimum Age on Non-Current Versions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to set an object lifecycle policy for a bucket in Google Cloud Storage which prevents removal of old non-current versions if the newer versions have not reached a minimum age.

Currently, I set the following flags and values in the lifecycle policy:

- Number of newer versions: 3
- Days since becoming non-current: 366 days

This policy will ensure that the oldest version is deleted once it is 366 days non-current and there are 2 newer versions and a live version.

**My Challenge: I would like to ensure that I always keep at least one non-current version that is at least 366 days old.**

In my current scenario, I could have

- Live version: 0 days old
- Version 2: 1 day old
- Version 1: 365 days old

(Age referring to days as a non-current version)

If I upload a new live version and a wait one day:

- Live version: 1 day old (new)
- Version 3: 1 day old (formerly live)
- Version 2: 2 days old
- Version 1: 366 days old <---- This now gets deleted and my oldest version is 2 days old.

Is it possible to avoid being left with only relatively new versions with versioning or do I have to use retention policies instead (which are [mutually exclusive with versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock))?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that with lifecycle rule. Retention policy is a good solution.

Comment: Will a retention policy also allow me to keep versions of the files?

Comment: Yes, it keeps all the blobs for the defined duration, current version or not.

Comment: But doesn't the documentation say they're mutually exclusive, meaning, once I turn on the retention rule I can't create any more versions?

Comment: Yes, you are right, you can not create more versions but any versioned objects remaining in a bucket when you apply a retention policy are also protected by the retention policy. Your scenario it's a little bit complicated.